# Not able to apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, apt

I'm trying to install postgreSQL BDR on my Ubuntu 14.04 following this simple guide: http://bdr-project.org/docs/next/installation-packages.html

I've done the steps provided which was:

1. Adding `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/2ndquadrant.list`
2. Importing repository key
3. `sudo apt-get update`

However, for some reason, running the last command produces a following output:
https://gist.github.com/mbajur/416588a165d62c17e9f0

That's awkward because i'm able to find exact the same tutorial for various of packages so it seems to be quite common thing to use that source.

What's the common way of dealing with such issues? Thanks in advance for any clues!

---

### Edit #1

My list files:

#### /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-backports main restricted universe multivers      deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

#### /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt_postgresql_org_pub_repos_apt.list

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
```

#### /etc/apt/sources.list.d/2ndquadrant.list

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
```

I've just noticed that those two last files has duplicated contents (might that be an issue?) but i'm not able to install given package anyway so there is something not right in here.

---

### Edit #2

I'm accepting A.B. answer but the real issue was that it seems that guys from postgres-bdr gave us wrong deb URL. It should be `deb http://packages.2ndquadrant.com/bdr/apt/ wheezy-2ndquadrant main`, not `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main`. That's why i was not able to install `postgresql-9.4-udr-plugin` package.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Edit (with comment) added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are two different things. The repository

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
```

works as you can see in your [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbajur/416588a165d62c17e9f0).

The problem is that the mirror `ftp.unina.it` doesn't exist in the [list](http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt) of the defined mirrors.

Use a different mirror or the main server

```
sudo sed -i 's/mirror:\/\/mirrors.ubuntu.com\/mirrors.txt/http:\/\/archive.ubuntu.com\/ubuntu/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt_postgresql_org_pub_repos_apt.list`,

the content is identical with the content of `etc/apt/sources.list.d/2ndquadrant.list`

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt_postgresql_org_pub_repos_apt.list
```

Update the software sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: But where did ubuntu finds this `ftp.unina.it` mirror? I can't find it in any of the sources files on my machine. What's more - everything worked fine before adding that line from original question

Comment: Updated my answer